# web crawler cannot exceed about 1MB/sec speed

Tags: python, web-scraping, twisted, scrapy, urllib3

I am building a webcrawler that gets 1-3 pages off a list of millions of domains, I am using Python with multi threading, i have tried multithreading with httplib, httplib2, urllib, urllib2, urllib3, requests, and curl(fastest of the bunch) as well as twisted, and scrapy but none of them are allowing me to use up more than about 10 mbits of bandwidth( I have 60 mbit speed), usually maxes out at around 100-300 threads and after that it causes failed requests.  I have also had this problem with php/curl.  I have a scraper that scrapes from google plus pages with urllib3 and the Threads module (Python) and that maxes out my 100mbit connection ( I believe this may be because it is re-using an open socket with the same host and google has a fast network response)

here is an example of one of my scripts using pycurl I am reading the urls from a csv file containing the urls.

```
import pycurl
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import cStringIO


def get(readq,writeq):
    buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
    while True:
        url=readq.get()

        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 15)
        c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
        c.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0')
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
        c.setopt(c.URL, url)
        try:
            c.perform()
            writeq.put(url+'  '+str(c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)))
        except:
            writeq.put('error  '+url)
print('hi')
readq=Queue()
writeq=Queue()

import csv
reader=csv.reader(open('alldataunq2.csv'))
sites = []
ct=0
for l in reader:
    if l[3] != '':
        readq.put('http://'+l[3])
        ct+=1
        if ct > 100000:
            break

t=[]
for i in range(100):
    Thread(target=get,args=(readq,writeq)).start()

while True:
    print(writeq.get())
```

the bottleneck is definitely network IO as my processor/memory is barely being used.  Has anyone had success in writing a similar scraper that was able to use a full 100mbit connection or more?

any input on how I can increase the speed of my scraping code is greatly appreciated

Comment: It could easily be that your ISP is detecting you pinging out so often to many different addresses and has decided to throttle your internet connection... What speeds are you achieving during normal internet access immediately afterwards?

Comment: i have tested this and immediately after stopping a running script I can achieve 55-60 mbit speed with speedtest.net  however i have noticed that i get better speeds when running my script on a remote server (perhaps the network connection is better equipped for a large number of request) I am testing out the the suggestions below and so far i have been able to achieve 5MB/sec speed on a server(not usingmy home internet connection) using scrapy-redis at which point it seems to be bottlenecked by the cpu of the server so that seems like a solution I will update this post after i do more tests

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors you need to keep in mind when optimizing crawling speed.

### Connection locality

In order to re-use connections effectively, you need to make sure that you're reusing connections for the same website. If you wait too long to hit an earlier host a second time, the connection could time out and that's no good. Opening new sockets is a relatively expensive operation so you want to avoid it at all costs. A naive heuristic to achieve this is to sort your download targets by host and download one host at a time, but then you run into the next problem...

### Spreading the load between hosts

Not all hosts have fat pipes, so you'll want to hit multiple hosts simultaneously—this also helps avoiding spamming a single host too much. A good strategy here is to have multiple workers, where each worker focuses on one host at a time. This way you can control the rate of downloads per host within the context of each worker, and each worker will maintain its own connection pool to reuse connections from.

### Worker specialization

One way to ruin your throughput is to mix your data processing routines (parse the HTML, extract links, whatever) with the fetching routines. A good strategy here is to do the minimal amount of processing work in the fetching workers, and simply save the data for a separate set of workers to pick up later and process (maybe on another machine, even).

Keeping these things in mind, you should be able to squeeze more out of your connection. Some unrelated suggestions: Consider using `wget`, you'd be surprised at how effective it is in doing simple crawls (it can even read from a giant manifest file).

Comment: -1 for gratuitous "use my favorite language instead" in an otherwise reasonable answer

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Edited. Python is my favourite language, actually. The content of the answer was not really specific to Python, and I honestly felt that Go would be a better tool for the job (as someone who has implemented a webcrawler in Python and authored urllib3/workerpool specifically for said tasks), but I hope this is to your satisfaction. In the future, please keep in mind that a downvote means "Not Useful."

Comment: uuhh… wat? If @shazow's entire post was "use golang", maybe? But as a one sentence suggestion at the end of an otherwise informative post?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can expect to get anywhere near your internet connection's max throughput when doing web scraping.

Scraping (and web browsing in general) involves making a lot of small requests. A good deal of that time is spent in connection set-up and tear down, and waiting on the remote end to begin delivering your content.  I'd guess that the time spent actively downloading content is probably around 50%.  If you were downloading a bunch of big files, then I think you'd see better average throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Try scrapy with [scrapy-redis](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis).

You will have to tune the [settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests): `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP`. Also make sure you have `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0` and `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False`.